# Binding ZIndex from DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, datatemplate

I have a View that is basically setup like this:

```
<Grid>
<ViewBox>
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
                      ItemTemplate="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyItemsDataTemplate}}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</ViewBox>
</Grid>
```

The DataTemplate used here can be reduced to this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AreaItemDisplayDataTemplate">
<Canvas Grid.ZIndex={Binding Z}>
    <Grid>
        // an shape is displayed here...
    </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

I would now expect the ZIndex to be bound to the Z property of the individual items. When i debug the code, i can also see, that the Z property getter is accessed when i would expect it (whenever i raise the propertychanged event for it, eg) so i assume the binding to work correctly.

However, the ZIndex is not working as expected. The binding to the value has no effect on the actual displayed Z Order. Where am i going wrong with this code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The content of the `DataTemplate` gets wrapped in a `ContentPresenter` so the `Canvas` in the `DataTemplate` isn't a direct child of the `ItemsPanel` `Grid`. That is the reason the `ZIndex` property doesn't do anything.

Move the `ZIndex` `Binding` to the `ItemContainerStyle` and it should work.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" 
              ItemTemplate="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyItemsDataTemplate}}"> 
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel> 
        <ItemsPanelTemplate> 
            <Grid /> 
        </ItemsPanelTemplate> 
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Grid.ZIndex" Value="{Binding Z}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</ItemsControl>
```